# Android writing and reading file from internal storage file path

Tags: android

I'm downloading and writing my file as below. The file is saved to a directory that it shouldn't.

`context.filesDir` returns `/data/user/0/com.lab/files` whereas file is saved to `data/data/com.lab/files`.

How could this happen while `openFileOutput` uses `context.filesDir` too?

#### Writing the file

```
context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .use {
                it.write(buf.toString().toByteArray())
            }
```

#### Reading the file

```
 val path1= "${context.filesDir}/filename" 
 val path2= "$data/data/com.lab/files/filename" 

 File(path1).exists() // is false
 File(path2).exists() // is true
```